# how to attach multiple file in android email?

Tags: android

I am trying to attach multiple file using intent.

below my code.

```
        Intent mSendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mSendIntent.setType("plain/text");
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "" });
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_CC, "");
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, "");
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "InfoMe Profile Request");
        ArrayList<String> yList = new ArrayList<String>();
        yList.add(path+filename);
        yList.add(path+"save.ime");
        ArrayList<Uri> y = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        for(String a:yList){
            y.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(a)));
        }
        mSendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                y);
        mSendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                Html.fromHtml(bodypart));
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mSendIntent,
                "Send mail..."));
```

but when i sent it than no attachment found. please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice tutorial on how to send multiple images via attachment: http://android-er.blogspot.hk/2012/10/start-activity-to-send-multi-images.html

FYI, `ACTION_SEND` is for a single attachment. For multiple files, you need `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`

The gist of it is, when you click on the button to invoke the `Intent` to send an email, you need something like this:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayUri);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choice App to send email:"));
```

Here the `arrayUri` is declared like this: `ArrayList<Uri> arrayUri = new ArrayList<Uri>();`

Follow the tutorial for a complete functioning example. They also have the entire project available for download.

Comment: I am trying to send one file and 5 images bt email depict no attachment.and also i used this code. so Is it possible to send one file with 5 images?

Comment: Unless you find a way to compress them into a zip or a rar, etc, you can't send multiple images in one file. And I did try example project the tutorial provides. And it worked just perfect for me. Perhaps you might compare your code with their and see if there are any major differences.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is clean until that

```
 Intent mailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
```